# Checking if these two are graph isomorphisms

Tags: graph-theory

I know a few graph invariants and it seemed that these two graphs do not have the same amount of circuit length $3$.
(our definition of a circuit is a closed path, a path being a walk with no repeated edges)

[image]

In particular, it seems that $G_1$ has $9$ circuits of length $3$ in the anti-clockwise direction (so there are $18$ circuits of length $3$ in total).

$G_2$ has only $6$ circuits of length $3$ in the anti-clockwise direction so it has $12$ circuits in total of length $3$.

So $G_1$ is not isomorphic to $G_2$, however, my solutions say that they are.

Comment: Where do you find $6$ or $9$ circuits of length $3$ in either? I found only two in $G_1$ ($a,c,d$ and $c,d,e$) and two in $G_2$ ($x,y,z$ and $x,y,t$).

Comment: The one I'm looking at for $G_1$.
$adca,dcad,cadc$ (so $3$ for that triangle)  
$cdec,decd,ecde$ (so $3$ for that triangle)  
  
Actually, I jsut found my mistake in the counting of $G_1$ after writing that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually these graphs are isomorphic. If you take f(a)=z
f(b)=u
f(e)=t
f(d)=x
f(c)=y
 f is an isomorphism because if ab is an edge in G1, f(a)f(b) is an edge in G2